# How to select different row in df as the column or delete the first few rows including the column?

Tags: pandas

I'm using read_csv to make a df, but the csv includes some garbage rows before the actual columns, the actual columns are located say in the 5th rows in the csv.

Here's the thing, I don't know how many garbage rows are there in advance and I can only read_csv once, so I can't use "head" or "skiprows" in read_csv.

So my question is how to select a different row as the columns in the df or just delete the first n rows including the columns? If I were to use "df.iloc[3:0]" the columns are still there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these "garbage rows" properly delimited? If not then you risk having problems reading the entire file, and the safer option is to read lines until a condition to determine the skiprows number.

Comment: I already determined the skiprows number but I couldn't read_csv again, so I wonder if it can be done in the df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Updated so that it also resets the index and does not include an index name:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[4].values
df = df.iloc[5:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you know your column names start in row 5 as in your example, you can do:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[4]
df = df.iloc[5:]
```

Comment: This is what im looking for, thanks a lot! Now i just have to figure out the indices since it's also copied, so now my columns row start from 5.

Comment: Happy to help. Please see edited answer with how you reset the index.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of garbage rows is determined, then you can use 'iloc', example the number of garbage rows is 3 firs rows (index 0,1,2), then you can use the following code to get all remaining actual data rows:

```
df=df.iloc[3:]
```

If the number of garbage rows is not determined, then you must search the index of first actual data rows from the garbage rows. so you can find the first index of actual data rows and can be used to get all remaining data rows.

```
df=df.iloc[n:]
```

n=fisrt index of actual data

Comment: Problem is the garbage row of columns is not indexed so your way wont delete the garbage columns